# Mysql "SELECT *' hangs

Tags: mysql

My MySQL database has two databases, let's call them `apple` and `banana`. `apple` has one table, let's call it `mydata`.

```
> use apple;
Database changed

> SELECT * FROM mydata;
...
3379 rows in set (0.00 sec)

> SELECT mydata.* FROM mydata;
...
3379 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Everything works fine when I use `SELECT *` within the same database. As soon as I switch databases I get strange behavior.

```
> use banana;
Database changed

> SELECT mydata.* FROM apple.mydata;
...
3379 rows in set (0.00 sec)

> SELECT * FROM apple.mydata;
[hangs!]
```

Why does this hang? What does MySQL think the `*` means that causes it to hang, while `mydata.*` is more specific and does not cause a hang.

Notes:

- According to 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST', the connection running the hanging query is not running a command, but is in state "Sleep".
- This problem is intermittent: my queries did this for a year and a half, and then all started freezing a few hours ago. Five minutes ago, they stopped freezing, and there is currently no problem.

Any ideas why an unqualified `SELECT *` doesn't run, while a qualified `SELECT mydata.*` runs instantly?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Comment: Any chance there's another query running at the same time that's locking the table? And if you try the SELECT mydata.* version lots of times, are you sure it never has the same problem?

Comment: It sounds like something is going on that you're not telling us about.

Comment: @Ben: There are 12 other open connections, and all are in the Sleep state.

Comment: @SamDufel: I'm not sure what you mean; I tried to give as much relevant information as possible. What else should I include?

Comment: @Jonathan - I can set up that exact schema you're describing on my own server and have it run with no problem.  You're not using any reserved keywords for table names, are you?

Comment: @SamDufel: No I'm not. Strangely, this problem is intermittent. This suggests to me some interaction with other queries, but I'm running mytop and there are no other queries running.

Comment: @Jonathan Any of the connections holding a lock on the tables?

Comment: @Jonathan try with a limit to see if it hangs, if now use a EXPLAIN to see what's happening